# Mejorar tiempo de carga NodeJS

Tags: mysql, nodejs, date

tengo una situacion. Vengo realizando un admin dashboard para mi sitio web. Utilizo la api de google analytics para consultar los datos y mostrarlos en mi app. El problema es que al realizar unas pocas consultas el tiempo de carga se hace elevadisimo... con 6 consultas a la API el tiempo de carga del dashboard es de 4 a 7 segundos. Como podria mejorarlo? Utilizo NodeJS expressJS y EJS para plasmar los datos. Deberia incorporar un framework en el frontend como react para reemplazar EJS?? les dejo una parte del codigo...

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  let query1 = "SELECT count(*) AS pedidosCount FROM pedidos;";
  let query2 = "SELECT count(*) AS juegos FROM juegos;";
  let query3 = "SELECT count(*) AS ultimo FROM `juegos` WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE);";
  let Pathing = req.path.replace(/\//g, "_");

  const getApGaData = async (propertyId = "******") => {
    const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient({
      keyFilename: credentialsJsonPath,
    });
    const [traficototal] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [
        { startDate: "30daysAgo", endDate: "today" },
        { startDate: "60daysAgo", endDate: "30daysAgo" },
        { startDate: "90daysAgo", endDate: "60daysAgo" },
        { startDate: "120daysAgo", endDate: "90daysAgo" },
      ],
      metrics: [{ name: "activeUsers" }],
    });
    const [visitsGraphA] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [{ startDate: "60daysAgo", endDate: "30daysAgo" }],
      metrics: [{ name: "activeUsers" }],
    });
    const [visitsGraphB] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [{ startDate: "90daysAgo", endDate: "60daysAgo" }],
      metrics: [{ name: "activeUsers" }],
    });
    const [visitsGraphC] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [{ startDate: "120daysAgo", endDate: "90daysAgo" }],
      metrics: [{ name: "activeUsers" }],
    });
    const [visitas] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [{ startDate: "2021-02-20", endDate: "today" }],
      dimensions: [{ name: "pagePathPlusQueryString" }, { name: "outbound" }],
      metrics: [{ name: "activeUsers" }, { name: "eventsPerSession" }],
      orderBys: [{ metric: { metricName: "activeUsers" }, desc: true }],
      limit: "5",
    });
    const [downloads] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dateRanges: [{ startDate: "2021-02-20", endDate: "today" }],
      dimensions: [{ name: "outbound" }],
      metrics: [{ name: "activeUsers" }],
    });
    const Total_traffic_value = traficototal.rows[0].metricValues[0].value;
    const Total_downloads_value = downloads.rowCount;
    db.query(query1 + query2 + query3, function (err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.render("home", {
        count: results[0],
        juegos: results[1],
        ultimoJuego: results[2],
        jsonOBJ: Total_traffic_value,
        PreviusMonth: visitsGraphA,
        ThreeMonthsAgo: visitsGraphB,
        FourMonthsAgo: visitsGraphC,
        downloads: Total_downloads_value,
        visits: visitas,
        page_active: Pathing,
      });
    });
  };
  getApGaData();
});
```

Comment: Pues, el lío puede estar en las consultas mismas. Prueba usando [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) para que revises cuánto toma cada consulta. Sin importar el framework, cargar los datos va a tomar lo mismo si hay líos ahí... por ejemplo, ese `WHERE month(xxx) = month(yyy)` tiene pinta de recorrer TODA la tabla procesando el campo que le dices pa extraerle el mes y eso es muy caro. Y así

Comment: @Alfabravo tengo una ruta en donde hago testeos, las consultas a mysql me las realiza en menos de un segundo.. el problema lo tengo con los call API... me llgan a tardar cada uno en promedio de 1 a 2 segundos... :(

Comment: A menos que G.A. te impida ejecutar varias consultas en paralelo, no veo para qué estás `awaiting`  el resultado. Eso se podría reformular con `Promise.all()`. Por otro lado, vamos más atrás: los resultados de analytics para el periodo entre 120 días atrás y 90 días atrás, te parece que cambia minuto a minuto? No. No cambia. Mételo en redis, en un json, o donde sea, pero no traigas dos veces una info que no va a cambiar al menos hasta mañana

Comment: Segundo: está bien que tus querys demoren (en tu percepción) poco, pero lo que podrías hacer en una sola (via UNION ALL) lo haces en 3 queries. Si son 3 queries de 10ms, da igual. Si son queries de 1s la importancia relativa es considerable. Incluso para resolver `SELECT 1 as total` el query parser ocupa un roundtrip.  De paso, ese resultado también podrías meterlo en un caché de 30s sin perjudicar la experiencia de usuario.

Comment: Tercero,  dejando de lado las llamadas al API que declaran una dimensión distinta, pareciera que la consulta de `activeUsers` la repites innecesariamente. En la primera, donde declaras cuatro rangos de fecha, obtienes lo necesario? En caso afirmativo, no veo para qué gatillas luego llamadas para los `activeUsers` de 3 periodos que ya debieras tener.

Comment: @ffflabs muchisimas gracias!! trabajare en todo eso e investigare lo de redis. Estuve viendo algo de Async.JS para ejecutar en paralelo me recomiendas eso o lo de promise.all??